# Using Drupal 8 Feeds with Xpath parser, can I concatenate two attribute values that appear in a single tag?

Tags: feeds

I have a dataset content type and an xml structure like this:

```
<dataset>
   <purpose>blah blah</purpose>
   <abstract>blah blah</abstract>
   <authors>blah blah1, blah blah2</authors>
   <ordered-authors>
      <author>blah blah</author>
      <author>blah blah</author>
      <author>blah blah</author>
   </ordered-authors>
   <tags>
      <themes>
         <theme name="xxx" rank="1"/>
         <theme name="yyy" rank="1"/>
      </themes>
   </tags>
</dataset>
```

I want to get the multiple attributes of each theme tag into a form like:
xxx-1, yyy-2, etc.
which will be used as entity references for each dataset, whether as an array, or a list that I then implode via a tamper. In Drupal 7 there were "dummy" fields to hold temporary values - I could create extra fields in the content type for this purpose but so far, that hasn't helped me find any way to query the xml and/or use available tamper options to combine the nested attributes to get a usable array of concatenated values (short of giving up with the feeds interface and moving to migrate). ANY help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution but it's not elegant. I used this query:
//theme/@name|//theme/@rank

and Imploded the resulting array to get theme1,rank1,theme2,rank2, etc,

then used a regex to replace every odd comma with a dash:
/(\w+)\W*,\W*(\w+)/
$1-$2

and then Exploded back to an array.

Would still like to know if there's a better alternative.